# Joining two tables on same date to form pairs of rows that do not have repetitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to form pair of rows when they have DATETIME IN COMMON, but the pairs should be formed in increasing order of the code, so the first code of table 1 must match the first code of table 2. Code that was used to form a pair should not be repeated:
Example:

```
**Table T1:
code  dtTime
#4,   10/10/2010 10:00 
#5,   10/10/2010 10:00
#6,   10/10/2010 10:00 


**Table T2:
code  dtTime
#1,   10/10/2010 10:00 
#2,   10/10/2010 10:00

**Pairs that must be formed:
T1.code, ISNULL(T1.dtTime,T2.dtTime),        T2.code
#4,      10/10/2010 10:00,                   #1
#5,      10/10/2010 10:00,                   #2
#6,      10/10/2010 10:00                    NULL
```

In the example above I cannot make the combination of #4 with #2 because the code #1 is smaller than #2, and also i cannot have #5 with #1, because #1 was already used to form a pair with #4.
I tried joining on dtTime, but it will result in all the possibilities(#4 with #1, #4 with #2, #5 with #1 and #5 with 2)

Comment: What should happen if the tables have an unequal number of rows for any particular datetime value?

Comment: It should show NULL in the side that do not have correspondation. I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can use a query like the following:

```
;WITH Table1 AS (
   SELECT code, dtTime,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtTime ORDER BY code) AS rn
   FROM T1
), Table2 AS (
   SELECT code, dtTime,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dtTime ORDER BY code) AS rn
   FROM T2
)
SELECT t1.code, 
       COALESCE(t1.dtTime, t2.dtTime) AS dtTime, 
       t2.code
FROM Table1 AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.dtTime = t2.dtTime AND t1.rn = t2.rn
```

The query joins together records having the same date. If more than one records with the same date exist, then records having the smallest `code` value for the date are joined together, followed by the records having the next biggest `code` value, etc.

Comment: Slight tweak - you want a `COALESCE` across both `dtTime` columns, now that we've confirmed that it is the `FULL OUTER JOIN` variant that's wanted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes this is correct, thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COALESCE()` with `FULL OUTER JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.code,COALESCE(t.dttime,s.dttime),s.code
FROM(SELECT t1.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.dttime ORDER BY t1.code) as rnk
     FROM T1) t
FULL OUTER JOIN(SELECT t2.*,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.dttime ORDER BY t2.code ) as rnk
                FROM T2) s
 ON(t.dttime = s.dttime AND t.rnk = s.rnk)
```